# Link não envia parâmetros e redireciona para Servlet

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Coloquei na minha pagina index em que tenho três links um com nome de Camisetas,Bermudas e Calças em que no `href` coloquei para que  quando clicasse no link fosse redirecionado para a servlet e enviasse os  parâmetros de acordo com o link, mas isso não acontece.

**Pagina JSP**

```html
<%
  String camisetas="Camisetas";
  String bermudas="Bermudas";
  String calcas="Calças";
%>

<div class="dropdown-content3">

 <li><a href="ListarProdutosPaginada?tipo=${camisetas}">Camisetas</a></li>
 <li><a href="ListarProdutosPaginada?tipo=${bermudas}"> Bermudas</a></li>
 <li><a href="ListarProdutosPaginada?tipo=${calcas}">Calças</a></li>
                      

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suas urls estão incompletas. Teria que ser algo assim:

```
<li>
 <a href="http://localhost:8080/app/ListarProdutosPaginada?tipo=${camisetas}">Camisetas</a>
</li>
```

No lugar de 'app' coloque o contexto que está usando na sua aplicação. Se não estiver usando um, deixe sem.

Comment: romarcio agora ele é redirecionado para servlet, mas ele não envia o parametro olha como fica o https quando eu clico no link http://localhost:8080/EccomerceJSP2/ListarProdutosPaginada?tipo=

Comment: Então o parâmetro `${camisetas}` deve estar vazio. Se você está recuperando esse valor daquelas variáveis que declarou na pagina como String, então deve usar ser assim: `?tipo=<%=  camisetas %>`

Comment: era isso mesmo vlw